# Creating MongoDB capped collection is too slow

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have an 8-core, 16GB RAM, 500GB HDD dedicated server and it takes too much time (several seconds) and resources (load over 5, normally below 1) to create a MongoDB capped collection:

```
db.createCollection("some.test", {capped:true, size:2147483647,});
```

It was quite a fast at the beginning when there were only a few capped collections (< 5) but now there are about 50 collections and it is really slow. Reads/writes are fast. There is 42% free disk space.

I think it takes the most time to reserve enough space for the collection on the disk.

Is there a solution to speed up the creation of the capped collections?

Comment: If the time is during allocation of the reserved space then I believe not because I don't think there is an option for dynamically allocating a capped collection like you can normal ones

Comment: When your application frequently creates new collection during normal operation, you are doing something wrong. When you would describe your use-case we could maybe suggest you a better course of action.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: Ext3. I use capped collection for logging user's server so it is created when user signs up.

Comment: Hmm I would try upgrading to ext4, I remember something about ext3 being slow with something, but it was a while ago so I don't fully remember

Answer (score 1):

Capped collections are preallocated when created and with ext3 that will block.

Ext4 or XFS is preferred[1] because they implement posix_fallocate, which means MongoDB can allocate large files quickly.

[1] http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/